# Some songs are not syncing with iCloud in iPhone

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, icloud

I have some songs that are not synced with iCloud. I reset the iPhone, removed all the songs in iPhone to resync, but it doesn't work. What's wrong with this and how can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, I fixed this bug doing this steps:

1. Remove the musics with this problem (also remove from iTunes Match).
2. Update iTunes Match (if you use)
3. Sync the iPhone
4. Add the musics again from my backup (not the backup from iTunes Library, I've all my musics in other place)
5. Sync the iPhone